# How to implement <isEmpty> easily in mybatis?

Tags: mybatis

In ibatis2.X it used to be:

```
<isEmpty property="userName" >
```

In MyBatis now it is something like:

```
<if test="userName != null && userName.trim().length !=0 " >
```

I would like to find an easy alternative to `isEmpty` in MyBatis. I found I can also use this construct:

```
<if test="@org.apache.commons.StringUtils@isEmpty(userName)" >
```

But it is not very convenient either.

Maybe I am missing something and there is `<isEmpty>` in MyBatis, or even something like `<if test="isEmpty(userName)" >` would be good enough. Could you advice?